# CircleCI for iOS - caching cocoapods dependencies

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, cocoapods, circleci

I'm trying to run my iOS testsuite in CircleCI using `fastlane scan`. Running the tests is working great, but the total time is increased a lot by installing dependencies from cocoapods.

I've tried to cache the Pods directory by doing the following, however, the checksum is changing between the `restore_cache` step and the `save_cache` step:

```
- restore_cache:
    key: 1-pods-{{ checksum "Podfile.lock" }}
- run:
    name: Install Pods
    command: pod install
- save_cache:
    key: 1-pods-{{ checksum "Podfile.lock" }}
    paths:
      - ./Pods
```

Essentially, the `pod install` causes the checksum to change even if none of the pods have changed.  As such, the key under which it's saved in cache never lines up with what's trying to be restored from cache.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: maybe your committed Podfile.lock isnt up to date? `pod install` will only change Podfile.lock if there were some changes on your podfile. I have the same exact way to restore and save and it works fine

Comment: Having this same issue. Were you able to get things working? I tried the key prefix solution, but that resulted in a sandbox out of sync error.

Comment: I actually see what the issue is. I used `cat` to print out my `Podfile.lock` before and after `pod_install`. The difference between what is checked in and what is generated is that I have a private repo source. In the generated version the lock file puts a `.git` at the end of the repo name. In my checked in version it does not. Weird though, both versions of cocoapods are the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to make this work. `restore_cache` accepts key prefixes (https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#restore_cache). So to fall back to an earlier cache you can use something like this:

```
- restore_cache:
    keys:
      - 1-pods-{{ checksum "Podfile.lock" }}
      - 1-pods-
```

There are some more specific guidelines here: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/ios-migrating-from-1-2/#installing-cocoapods

Answer (score 1):

These are the complete steps.

```
  - restore_cache:
      key: 1-pods-{{ checksum "Podfile.lock" }}
  - run:
      name: Install CocoaPods
      command: |
        if [ ! -d "Pods" ]
        then
           curl https://cocoapods-specs.circleci.com/fetch-cocoapods-repo-from-s3.sh | bash -s cf
          bundle exec pod install
        fi
  - save_cache:
      key: 1-pods-{{ checksum "Podfile.lock" }}
      paths:
        - ./Pods
```

First step is to restore cache.

Second step, if cache is not found, update the pods repo from circleci mirror and install pods. This step takes around 5 minutes so you better skip it if unnecessary.

Third step, save cache if key is still not occupied

source: https://medium.com/wandercodes/how-to-save-time-in-circleci-when-using-pods-4e00cd419ad8

Answer (score 1):

OK, after running into this exact issue I solved it for myself. I'll leave solution here in case this ends up being the same for others.

## What?

When trying to cache and restore cocoapod dependencies on circleci the checksum being used for my cache key is different at restore when compared to save; resulting in never finding a cache key match.

## Why?

When circleci was adding my repo as a source it was including the `.git` extension to my repo. However, when I added the repo to my own machine (i.e., `pod repo add <name> <url>` I did *not* include the extension. So, on my local machine when I'd run `pod install` my `Podfile.lock` would list my private repo without the `.git`, which of course factors into the generation of the checksum. Then on circleci, it would go through the same process, but generate a `Podfile.lock` which *did* include the `.git` extension, in turn causing a different checksum, and ultimately a different cache key.

## Solution

Remove the private repo from my local machine (i.e., `pod repo remove <name>`) and add it back again, being sure to include the `.git` extension as part of the url (i.e., `pod repo add <name> https://my-vcs.com/path-to/repo.git`).

One note regarding using the fallback method mentioned above. This actually resulted in a `Sandbox out of sync` error, because the old caches contained pods that were no longer aligned with the current state of the app. So I'd probably avoid using this technique.